# When debugging NGINX configuration files, is there a way to print log messages

Tags: nginx, logging

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy configuration for WSS to WS, and for HTTPS to still work as well. It would help I think, if I had some idea which parts of the conf.d/myserver conf file were being used. Is there some way to put trace or print statements into the access log from within the config file? For example, if my server block or location block for the WSS rules is used, to print "processing location WSS rules" . Or if my map or my server block is entered/active, etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request processing internals can be seen in nginx debug log. How to actually enable debug logging depends on the version and distribution you are using.

With `nginx.org` built Debian packages, one needs to take two steps:

1. Change level to `debug` within `error_log` directive.
2. `systemctl stop nginx && systemctl start nginx-debug`.

The debug log is really verbose, so it takes some effort to see the processing of locations over there.

Comment: Thank you Tero for responding. I'm using 1.22 release without compiling, on Debian 11. I tried  changing nginx.conf to have 'error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;' and also added the same line to my WSS location in my conf.d/myserver.conf file. Neither the error log or access log show any further details.

Comment: I found this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html that explains to stop the nginx service and start the nginx-debug service for debugging in my case.

Comment: My second step above explained that you need to start `nginx-debug`.

Comment: Actually debian comes with the bundled debug support:  --with-debug